# Canon X MARK I PRO - Integral calculation with steps

Tags: integration, calculator

I have a problem with my calculator. I want to calculate integral $\int_0^{1.2} ln(1 + x^2)$ on a calculator but I want to do it with step $0.2$. The result should be $0.496390855...$ I am able to calculate the integral on the calculator without the step, easily using the integral button, filling or input fields. But I am not able to define the step. I checked manual for the calculator and it says:

[image]
[image]

I tried the manual step by step but it throws syntax error. Could you tell me how to type in this expression?

[Here](http://ugp01.c-ij.com/cal/webmanual/WebPortal/html/ptl-manual_index.html?lang=en&area=me&model=X%20Mark%20I%20Pro) is a link to the manual for the calculator.

The manual clearly says that there should be typed: `<integral symbol> <expression> <,> <start_value> <,> <end_value> <,> <step>)`

Comment: This post should not be here.

Comment: It may (loosely?) fit under "Software that mathematicians use (except Mathematica, which has its own Stack Exchange site)".